# Vectorize IF statement

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize an if statement in Matlab and I am not sure how to do it. I want to assign a 'N' for positive values and 'S' for negative values. I want to avoid a for loop but here is my code:

```
LatDD = [23.0,12.3,-43.2,9.9,-40.7];
LatDir = ['' '' '' '' ''];
if (LatDD < 0)
    LatDir = 'S'
else
    LatDir = 'N'
end
```

Obviously this fails to do what I want because it really only checks the first element of LatDD. I could easily do a for loop but I want it to be vectorized. I tried logical indexing but all that got me was another vector with zeroes or ones which I would have to check with a for loop anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use logical indexing here, you just have to do it twice

```
LatDD = [23.0,12.3,-43.2,9.9,-40.7];
LatDir = ['' '' '' '' ''];

LatDir(LatDD < 0) = 'S';
LatDir(LatDD >= 0) = 'N';
```

Since you have a binary choice here, you could even skip a step by prefilling `LatDir` with all `'N'` and just changing the ones corresponding to negative `LatDD` values to `'S'`

```
LatDD = [23.0,12.3,-43.2,9.9,-40.7];
LatDir = ['N' 'N' 'N' 'N' 'N'];

LatDir(LatDD < 0) = 'S';
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner -

```
char('S'*(LatDD<0) + 'N'*(~(LatDD<0)))
```

Sample run -

```
>> LatDD = [23.0,12.3,-43.2,9.9,-40.7];
>> LatDir = ['' '' '' '' ''];
>> char('S'*(LatDD<0) + 'N'*(~(LatDD<0)))
ans =
NNSNS
```

Comment: This also works but it is confusing for beginners like me. Thanks for answering though. It helps me and others learn the tricks.